# NestJS - How to create nested schema with decorators

Tags: mongoose, schema, nestjs, mongoose-schema

Let's say I want to build the below schema with mongoose:

```js
const userSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    firstName: String,
    lastName: String
  }
})
```

How can I do it with NestJS decorators (`@Schema()` & `@Prop()`)?

I try this method, but no luck:

```js
@Schema()
class Name {
  @Prop()
  firstName: string;

  @Prop()
  lastName: string;
}

@Schema()
class User extends Document {
  @Prop({ type: Name })
  name: Name;
}
```

I also don't want to use the `raw()` method.

Comment: why not `raw()`?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Here's my method which works great and **doesn't involve removing @schema()**:

```js
// Nested Schema
@Schema()
export class BodyApi extends Document {
  @Prop({ required: true })
  type: string;

  @Prop()
  content: string;
}
export const BodySchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(BodyApi);

// Parent Schema
@Schema()
export class ChaptersApi extends Document {
  // Array example
  @Prop({ type: [BodySchema], default: [] })
  body: BodyContentInterface[];

  // Single example
  @Prop({ type: BodySchema })
  body: BodyContentInterface;
}
export const ChaptersSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(ChaptersApi);
```

This saves correctly and shows the timestamps when you have that option set on your schema

Comment: Hmmm, looks promising. Gonna try it out soon 

Comment: will it create 2 separate collections? I want a single collection.

Comment: @AnkitTanna No, only the schema you pass to `MongooseModule.forFeature` in the module will get created.

Comment: Is BodyContentInterface supposed to be the same as BodyApi? Its not defined anywhere

Comment: If we do not pass the subdocument schema into `MongooseModule`, then how should we use and populate subdocument inside the corresponding `service.ts`

Comment: @AlexanderK1987, you don't need to pass it to the MongooseModule tho, I was making the same mistake and once I removed them, those collections never came back. I guess you'd have to stick to using those models inside of their own modules and that's a good practice.

Comment: This solution creates a collection for the sub document on the fly. To create an embedded document without creating the collection, read my answer below

Comment: @austinthedeveloper what is BodyContentInterface please?
class annotated with @Schema()? Why in your example classes annotated with @Scehma() needs to extend Document? At least in nestjs docs, i cant find example where they extends from Document any schema.

Comment: @austinthedeveloper or maybe it is HydratedDocument?
Something like:
export type BodyContentInterface = HydratedDocument<BodyApi>?

Answer (score 14):

I haven't found this part of NestJS to be flexible enough. A working solution (tested) for me is the following:

```js
@Schema({_id: false}) // _id:false is optional
class Name {
  @Prop() // any options will be evaluated
  firstName: string; // data type will be checked

  @Prop()
  lastName: string;
}

@Schema()
class User {
  @Prop({type: Name}) // {type: Name} can be omitted
  name: Name;
}
```

Defining your schemas this way will keep everything (class decorators, passed options, data types verification, NestJS functionalities, etc.) working as expected. The only "issue" is that `_id` properties will be created for each `@Schema` and you might not want that, like in your case. You can avoid that by adding `{_id: false}` as an options object to your `@Schema()`. Keep in mind, that any further nested schemas won't be prevented from creating `_id` properties, e.g.

This:

```js
@Schema() // will create _id filed
class Father {
  age: number;
  name: string;
}

@Schema({_id: false}) // won't create _id field
class Parents {
  @Prop()
  father: Father;

  @Prop()
  mother: string;
}

@Schema()
class Person {
  @Prop()
  parents: Parents;
}
```

will produce this:

```js
{
  _id: ObjectId('someIdThatMongoGenerated'),
  parents: {
    father: {
      _id: ObjectId('someIdThatMongoGenerated'),
      age: 40,
      name: Jon Doe
    },
    mother: Jane Doe
  }
}
```

The other workaround is to use native mongoose for creating your schemas in NestJS, like so:

```js
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    firstName: {
      type: String, // note uppercase
      required: true // optional
    },
    lastName: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: This solution work perfectly for me, including prop args like `default`, `get`/`set` and so on. Hope I know this method earlier

Answer (score 6):

Changes made:

1. No `@Schema` decorator for the sub-document class
2. Sub-document class needs to extend `Document` from `'mongoose'`

`user.schema.ts`

```
import { Document } from 'mongoose';

@Schema()
export class User extends Document {
  @Prop({ type: Name })
  name: Name;
}

export const UserSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(User);
```

`name.schema.ts`

```
import { Document } from 'mongoose';

export class Name extends Document {
  @Prop({ default: " " })
  firstName: string;

  @Prop({ default: " " })
  lastName: string;
}
```

Comment: Will it work for unique: true for a property inside an array of sub document?

Comment: This solution will correctly create a nested object (user.name.firstName) but the type (:string) validation will not work. You will be allowed to write a number or another type into the firstName field. It's not a working solution.

Comment: I'm following the same the but my defaults are not being set on the nested object.

Answer (score 2):

Try to remove @schema() decorator from the nested "Name", leaving it only at the root of your document.

Also remember to extend 'mongoose.Document' at the root level.

```js
    import { Prop, Schema, SchemaFactory, } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
    import { Document  } from 'mongoose';
        
    class Name {
      @Prop()
      firstName: string;
    
      @Prop()
      lastName: string;
    }
    
    @Schema()
    class User extends Document {
      @Prop({ type: Name })
      name: Name;
    }
    export const userSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(user);
```

Comment: What is the problem? Are you getting any error messages? I just did that structure in my project and it is working fine

Comment: I don't know, I don't get any error, it just doesn't work. Try to put a default value on a nested property like 'firstName', the default value won't set, showing there's a problem.

Comment: https://discordapp.com/channels/520622812742811698/606125380817911828/738145362635915275

Answer (score 2):

You can also use this.

```js
    @Schema()
    class User extends Document {
      @Prop({ type:  { firstName: String, lastName: String })
      name: Name;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

**Top-Level Document**

```js
import { Prop, Schema, SchemaFactory } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { HydratedDocument } from 'mongoose';
import { FanNotification } from './notification.schema';

export type FanDocument = HydratedDocument<Fan>;

@Schema()
export class Fan {

  @Prop({ type: FanNotification, default: () => ({}) })
  notifications: FanNotification;

}

export const FanSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(Fan);
```

I used `default: () => ({})` to create defaults.

**Embedded Document**

```js
import { Prop, Schema } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { AllMethod } from 'common/types';
import { Schema as MongooseSchema } from 'mongoose';

@Schema({ _id: false })
export class FanNotification {
  @Prop({
    type: MongooseSchema.Types.Mixed,
    default: { sms: true, email: true },
  })
  chat: AllMethod;

}
```

To make sure `@Prop()`s are recognized, and prevent automatic collection creation, I passed `{ _id: false }`.

Comment: You should use `markModified()` for the sub-document when anything has changed on that path.

Answer (score -5):

Firstly, you should use mongoose schema for this case. It is clear & simple:

```
export const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    name: [UserNameSchema],
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  },
);
```

If you don't like this approach, you should follow the offical documentation:

```
@Prop(raw({
  firstName: { type: String },
  lastName: { type: String }
}))
details: Record<string, any>;
```

Comment: I want to use my typescript model both in frontend and backend and I save this model in a shared folder. With this approach, I can't do this anymore!

Comment: Totally, It should not. Because the schemas and model are different. You should define interface files as well.

The return data should be compatibility with interface. Then share the interface to frontend. Using OpenAPI generator.

Comment: the question clearly states using Nest decorators.